# I wrote a closure to add draggable elements to a map. I expected the enclosre to preserve values. It doesn't. Why not?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, closures

I want to annotate a route on a map using vanilla javascript.  To that end, I have a canvas element, a draw routine to 'connect' divs to points on the map, a closure to construct small divs, and another closure to make the divs draggable, so they can be more conveniently positioned over the map.  In both closures, I'm having what I think is the same problem.

js & HTML to show the problem with the make-it-draggable closure, `makeDraggable`, are below.  The outermost function declares a variable, `dragThis`.  The dragstart handler assigns it value.  `onDragOver` and `onDrop` use it.  The debugger says `dragThis` is in the same `makeDraggable` closure at every use. I expected this approach to simplify the overall structure and efficiency of the code.

**The problem**: When the drag and drop handlers fire, `dragThis` doesn't have the value assigned in `dragStart`.  Why?(???)  (In fact, the value in the drag and drop handlers seems to be the id of the element in the first call to makedraggable by test.)

Associated questions:

- I use the setData/getData methods of the dataTransfer object.  For the life of me, i don't understand the first argument of those functions, 'format'.  It seems to have nothing whatever to do with 'format' (save that it changes 'text' to 'text/plain' internally), and everything to do with identifying a datum.  The value of 'format' can be just about any string.  From the W3: *The API *does not enforce* the use of MIME types; other values can be used as well.*  'name' would seem to be a more appropriate, um, name.  Am i missing something?  Shouldn't ducks be called ducks? This hardly seems deserving of a separate question, but I'm curious and don't know how else to ask.
- MDN says the event object's pageX, pageY "...include any portion of the page not currently visible."  They do not seem to include non-visible portions of scrolled elements, so that seems false.  What am i missing?  (And does my pageXY function correctly calculate a position that *does* take those invisible bits properly into account?  It seems to work, but my example may be too simple.)
- Firefox and fiddle seem happy with my code.  Chrome, though, at drop time in `placeEl`, thinks 'el' in 'el.style.left =...' is null: **TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null...**.  Nonetheless, it is happy with the next line, and magically goes on to properly position the div.

I put the code at https://jsfiddle.net/HerbX/g7zv1ok2/1/  Maybe its still there.  I've hardwired illustrative divs into the html.

Apparently having referenced the fiddle, I need to put the code here as well:

```
var MYSTUFF = {
    makeDraggable:function(el, elChart) {
      var dragThis = el;
        var ops = {capture:true, useCapture:true};
        el.draggable = true;
        el.addEventListener('dragstart', onDragStart, ops);
        console.log("dragstart listener added to " + el.id);
        if (elChart.dataset.dragover === undefined) {
            elChart.addEventListener('dragover', onDragOver, ops);
            elChart.addEventListener('drop', onDrop, ops);
            elChart.dataset.dragover = 'dragover';
            console.log("dragover listener added to " + elChart.id);
        }
        return el;

        function onDragStart(ev) {
            var clickXY;
            dragThis = ev.target;
            clickXY = MYSTUFF.pageXY(ev);
            ev.dataTransfer.clearData();
            ev.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain',toStr(ev.target.id, ev.target.offsetLeft, ev.target.offsetTop, clickXY.x, clickXY.y));
            ev.dataTransfer.setData('foo', ev.target.id);
            console.log("dragStart: dragThis.id is " + dragThis.id + ", dT = " + ev.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain'));
            }

        function onDragOver(ev){
            var pos;                // new (style.top, style.left)
            var canvasid;           // canvas, if px, py exist
            var params, el;
            var foo;
            ev.preventDefault();
            params = ev.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain').split(';')
            foo = ev.dataTransfer.getData('foo');
            el = document.getElementById(params[0]);
            pos = placeEl(ev, el);  // Reposition el by delta(mouse)
            console.log("onDragOver: dragThis.id = " + dragThis.id + '; foo = ' + foo);
        }

        function onDrop(ev) {
            var canvasTemp, canvasid, ctx;
            var dT, params;
            var el, els;
            ev.preventDefault();
            dT = ev.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain');
            params = dT.split(';');
            console.log("onDrop event: dragThis.id is " + dragThis.id + ", dT is " + dT);
            el = document.getElementById(params[0]);
            placeEl(ev,el);                                   //Reposition el, ignore return.
        }

        function toStr() {
//  arguments => ;-delimited string.  Args must be scalar numbers.              
            var delim='';
            var s = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
                if (isNaN(arguments[i])) {
                    s += delim + arguments[i];
                } else {
                    s += delim + arguments[i].toFixed(1);
                }
                delim = ";";
            }
            return s;
        }

        function placeEl(ev,el) {
/*  Re-position el by delta(mouse position)             */
            var params;
            var dx, dy;
            var pos;
            var cursorXY;
            params = ev.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain').split(';');
            cursorXY = MYSTUFF.pageXY(ev);
            dx = cursorXY.x - parseFloat(params[3]);
            dy = cursorXY.y - parseFloat(params[4]);
            pos = {x:parseFloat(params[1]) + dx, y:parseFloat(params[2]) + dy};
            el.style.left = pos.x + 'px';
          el.style.top =  pos.y + 'px';
            return pos;
        }
    },

    reportXY: function(ev) {
        let x, y, abs, sAbs;
        let msg = document.getElementById('msg');
        let el = ev.srcElement;
        let id = el.id;
        if (id === "") id = el.tagName;
        x = event.pageX.toFixed(0);
        y = event.pageY.toFixed(0);
        abs = MYSTUFF.pageXY(ev);
        sAbs = "(" + abs.x + "," + abs.y + ")";
        msg.innerText = "In " + id + ", cursor @ Page XY: (" + x + "," + y +").  Including scrolls, cursor @ " + sAbs;
    },

    pageXY:function(ev) {
        let x = ev.pageX;
        let y = ev.pageY;
        let scrollX, scrollY, tagName, el;

        el = ev.srcElement;
        tagName = el.tagName;
        scrollX = el.scrollLeft;
        scrollY = el.scrollTop;
        while (tagName !== 'HTML') {
            el = el.parentElement;
            tagName = el.tagName;
            scrollX += el.scrollLeft;
            scrollY += el.scrollTop;
        }
        return {x:x+scrollX, y:y+scrollY}
    }
}
/* test1() only tests makeDraggable.  It uses elements hardwired into the HTML.*/
function test1() {
    var elChart = document.getElementById('chartPosRef');
    var div = document.getElementById('div-0');
    MYSTUFF.makeDraggable(div, elChart);

    div = document.getElementById('div-1');
    MYSTUFF.makeDraggable(div,elChart);

    div = document.getElementById('div-2');
    MYSTUFF.makeDraggable(div,elChart); 

    div = document.getElementById('div-3');
    MYSTUFF.makeDraggable(div,elChart);
}
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
      window.addEventListener('mousemove', MYSTUFF.reportXY);
    test1();
});
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>connected</title>
        <style>     
        .small {
            position:absolute;
            width:7em;
            background-color:#e6ffe6;
            }
        .red {
            background-color:red;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="js/Q1.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
<div id="chartCtnr"  style="text-align:center;">
    <div id="chartResz" class="resizeable" style="width:500px;height:500px;display:inline-block">
      <div id="chartScroll" style="overflow:auto;height:100%;width:100%;display:inline-block;">
        <div id="chartPosRef" class="freezer" style="position:relative">

                    <canvas id="connectedCanvas"  class="red" width="3718" height="2614" title="Track">This to draw the connected track</canvas>
                  <div id='div-0' class='small' style='top:100px;left:100px;'>this is div-0</div>
                  <div id='div-1' class='small' style='top:120px;left:080px;'>this is div-1</div>
                  <div id='div-2' class='small' style='top:140px;left:100px;'>this is div-2</div>
                  <div id='div-3' class='small' style='top:160px;left:080px;'>this is div-3</div>
        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div id='msg'>this is a message</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, part of the problem is that 'makeDraggable' is not a closure (I think).  Wrap it with a function that returns it ('dragger'), define dragStart at the top of that wrapper, and complete the function makeDraggable in dragger (it does not need to wrap onDragStart etc) and you will have a closure.  Zut alors, this took an absurdly long time to figure out!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the 'closure' wasn't a closure.  Now it is, after reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures a little more carefully, and this works. Note that dragStart (and a couple of other variables) are defined at the top of 'dragger' (as, in effect, are makeDraggable, onDragStart and so on.)

Next to do (but not here cuz i doubt that anyone cares...) is to add variables needed to draw lines connecting the divs to points on the map (non-existent here).  Most are closure variables, and setting them will add little to no overhead to the drag operation - largely the point of this exercise.

setData('foo', target.id) remains because I'd still like to know why documentation refers to that first argument as a 'format'.

```
var MYSTUFF = {
    dragger: function() {
    var dragThis;           // element being dragged
        var clickXY;      // click-position relative to ULC of scrolled area
        var elStartXY;    // Initial position of dragThis rel to ULC of scrolled area.
        var canvas; 
        return makeDraggable;

        function makeDraggable (el, elChart) {
        var ops = {capture:true, useCapture:true};
        dragThis = el;
        el.draggable = true;
        el.addEventListener('dragstart', onDragStart, ops);
        if (elChart.dataset.dragover === undefined) {
            elChart.addEventListener('dragover', onDragOver, ops);
            elChart.addEventListener('drop', onDrop, ops);
            elChart.dataset.dragover = 'dragover';  
        }
        return el;
    }

        function onDragStart(ev) {
      dragThis = ev.target;
        clickXY = MYSTUFF.pageXY(ev);
        elStartXY = {x:ev.target.offsetLeft, y:ev.target.offsetTop};
        ev.dataTransfer.setData('foo', ev.target.id);
    }

        function onDragOver(ev){
        var pos;                // new (style.top, style.left)
        var canvasid;           // canvas, if px, py exist
        var params, el;
        var foo;
        ev.preventDefault();
        pos = placeEl(ev,dragThis);
    }

        function onDrop(ev) {
        var canvasTemp, canvasid, ctx;
        var dT, params;
        var el, els;
        ev.preventDefault();
        placeEl(ev,dragThis);
        }

        function toStr() {
//  arguments => ;-delimited string.  Args must be scalar numbers.              
        var delim='';
        var s = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            if (isNaN(arguments[i])) {
                s += delim + arguments[i];
            } else {
                s += delim + arguments[i].toFixed(1);
            }
            delim = ";";
        }
        return s;
    }

        function placeEl(ev,el) {
/*  Re-position el by delta(mouse position)             */
        var params;
        var dx, dy;
        var pos;
        var cursorXY;
        cursorXY = MYSTUFF.pageXY(ev);
        dx = cursorXY.x - clickXY.x;
        dy = cursorXY.y - clickXY.y;
        pos = {x:elStartXY.x + dx, y:elStartXY.y + dy};
        el.style.left = pos.x + 'px';
        el.style.top =  pos.y + 'px';
        return pos;
    }
}, // end 'dragger'

    reportXY: function(ev) {
        let x, y, abs, sAbs;
        let msg = document.getElementById('msg');
        let el = ev.srcElement;
        let id = el.id;
        if (id === "") id = el.tagName;
        x = event.pageX.toFixed(0);
        y = event.pageY.toFixed(0);
        abs = MYSTUFF.pageXY(ev);
        sAbs = "(" + abs.x + "," + abs.y + ")";
        msg.innerText = "In " + id + ", cursor @ Page XY: (" + x + "," + y +").  Including scrolls, cursor @ " + sAbs;
    },

    pageXY:function(ev) {
        let x = ev.pageX;
        let y = ev.pageY;
        let scrollX, scrollY, tagName, el;

        el = ev.srcElement;
        tagName = el.tagName;
        scrollX = el.scrollLeft;
        scrollY = el.scrollTop;
        while (tagName !== 'HTML') {
            el = el.parentElement;
            tagName = el.tagName;
            scrollX += el.scrollLeft;
            scrollY += el.scrollTop;
        }
        return {x:x+scrollX, y:y+scrollY}
    }
}
/* test1() only tests makeDraggable.  It uses elements hardwired into the HTML.*/
function test1() {
    md = MYSTUFF.dragger();
    var elChart = document.getElementById('chartPosRef');
    var div = document.getElementById('div-0');

  md(div, elChart);
    div = document.getElementById('div-1');

    md(div, elChart);
    div = document.getElementById('div-2');
  md(div, elChart);

    div = document.getElementById('div-3');
  md(div, elChart);
}
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
      window.addEventListener('mousemove', MYSTUFF.reportXY);
    test1();
});
```